# Vim - how to auto complete buffer contents in command-line mode

Tags: vim, autocomplete, substitution

Use case: I have a buffer

```
variable1
variable2
variable3
```

i want to replace `variable1` with `variable3` using

```
:%s/vari<TAB>/vari<TAB><TAB><TAB>
```

can this be done somehow? I don't want to have to type out or manually copy words

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As Rob mentioned, consider using [vi.se] for questions on Vim, it's a Stack Exchange dedicated for questions on Vi / Vim / NeoVim.

Comment: @filbranden I'd say there's nothing wrong with asking vim related questions on stack overflow when using the vim tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I vaguely remembered [this old plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2222) from way back and, well… it still seems to do the job:

[image: compl]

Comment: Oh, amazing! just what i was looking for! Amazing it still works after 11 years (`Plug 'vim-scripts/cmdline-completion'`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [command-line window](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-window) (see `:help cmdline-window`) to use regular Insert mode to write an Ex command-line such as `:s`.

You can either use `q:` from Normal mode to access the command-line window, or use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> from the Ex command-line (after typing `:` and even starting to write a command such as `:%s/vari`...)

Once in the command-line window, you can use `i` (or `a`, `A`, etc.) to enter Insert mode, and then you can use the usual [completion keystrokes](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#compl-generic) such as <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to complete from contents of other visible buffers.

Once the `:%s` command is complete, you can simply press <kbd>Return</kbd> to have the command from the command-line window executed as a regular Ex command.

Comment: Interesting way of doing it! Getting the buffer autocompletion to do anything inside the command palette  is the next step i guess. Does it work for you? wondering if it's my setup thats broke

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy Yes, it works for me with Ctrl+N and Ctrl+P. Vim with no plug-ins enabled. Not sure if you have some auto-completion plug-ins that might be hooking into those keystrokes?